# How to allow ONLY whatsapp traffic on office wi-fi network?

Tags: security, firewall

I need to provide our office with wi-fi, but they should *only* be able to use it for whatsapp application. Everything else should be blocked.

I've looked at some UTM's which promise "Application Control" but in all my google search I couldn't find a successful case of exactly what I am trying to do.

I currently do not have a firewall on this internet service.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What firewall you have?

Comment: none on this internet service @yagmoth555. I have linux machines available that I can turn into a firewall if there is a solution that calls for that

Comment: sophos utm seem to be able to do it, I would give it a try

Answer (score 5):

[Here](https://github.com/ukanth/afwall/wiki/HOWTO-blocking-WhatsApp) you can find the hostnames/IPs/ports used by both iOS and Android Whatsapp application.

In short:

- enable DNS traffic;
- enable all traffic for `*.whatsapp.net` and `*.whatsapp.com`
- enable all traffic for the IPv4 address listed below;
- block all other traffic;

**IPv4 list:** (note: the IPs can change in the future)

```
209.95.33.68 (ipv4 only but there is no ipv6 atm?)
208.43.115.202
208.43.122.131 - 208.43.122.135
208.43.244.168
208.43.244.169
208.43.244.170
208.43.244.171
208.43.244.172
208.43.244.174
208.43.244.175
208.43.96.4
208.43.96.5
208.43.96.6
208.43.96.7
208.43.97.156
192.155.212.202
192.155.212.203
184.172.19.64
184.172.19.65
184.172.19.66
184.172.19.69
184.172.19.70
184.172.19.71
184.172.19.79
184.172.19.81
184.172.19.84
184.172.19.86
184.172.19.89
184.172.19.92
184.172.19.94
184.172.19.95
184.173.136.64
184.173.136.65
184.173.136.66
184.173.136.67
184.173.136.68
184.173.136.69
184.173.136.70
184.173.136.71
184.173.136.72
184.173.136.73
184.173.136.74
184.173.136.75
184.173.136.76
184.173.136.77
184.173.136.79
184.173.136.80
184.173.136.81
184.173.136.82
184.173.136.83
184.173.136.84
184.173.136.85
184.173.136.86
184.173.136.87
184.173.136.88
184.173.136.89
184.173.136.90
184.173.136.91
184.173.136.93
184.173.136.94
184.173.136.95
184.173.147.38
184.173.147.53
184.173.147.39
174.123.168.2
174.37.240.116
108.168.174.7
75.119.222.13
64.233.162.141
50.22.198.205
50.22.199.44
50.22.203.212
50.22.225.69
50.22.210.128
50.22.210.129
50.22.210.130
50.22.210.131
50.22.210.132
50.22.210.133
50.22.210.134
50.22.210.135
50.22.210.136
50.22.210.137
50.22.210.138
50.22.210.141
50.22.210.142
50.22.210.143
50.22.210.144
50.22.210.145
50.22.210.146
50.22.210.147
50.22.210.148
50.22.210.149
50.22.210.150
50.22.210.151
50.22.210.152
50.22.210.153
50.22.210.154
50.22.210.155
50.22.210.158
50.22.210.159
50.22.210.32
50.22.210.33
50.22.213.140
50.22.213.141
50.22.213.142
50.22.213.143
50.22.227.220
50.22.227.222
50.22.227.224
50.22.227.225
50.22.227.226
50.22.227.227
50.22.235.124
50.22.235.125
50.22.235.126
50.22.235.127
50.23.142.160
50.23.142.161
50.23.142.162
50.23.142.163
50.23.142.168
50.23.142.169
50.23.142.170
50.23.142.173
50.23.142.174
50.23.142.175
50.23.142.176
50.23.142.177
50.23.142.180
50.23.142.181
50.23.142.182
50.23.142.190
50.23.142.191
50.97.57.148
```

Comment: BTW I think this solution would allow WhatsApp desktop too.

Comment: Thannk you! Question: do I NEED to buy a UTM, or can I configure a linux machine as a my router/gateway and add those rules you suggest to the iptables of that machine?

Comment: The above rules are at layer3/4 (ie: IP/TCP) and DNS only. This means you can use them without depending on a UTM device.

Answer (score 1):

Try to enable these

### For IP Addresses Range

Download list of as .zip [IP Addresses](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/guides/network-requirements/#ipaddresses)
 click on **WhatsApp server IP addresses and ranges (.zip file)**

### For HostNames

```
.*.cdn.whatsapp.net
g.whatsapp.net
graph.facebook.com
graph.whatsapp.com
media-.*.cdn.whatsapp.net
media..*.fna.whatsapp.net
mmg.whatsapp.net
pps.whatsapp.net
static.whatsapp.net
v.whatsapp.net
```

for more Information check [network-requirements](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/guides/network-requirements/) From Facebook/whatsapp

Comment: url for that list is expired and is not longer available.

Comment: if you mean hostnames it's the newest @MTG